# cant make a smooth rotation in rotate css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a smooth landing with a rocket, but I'm not being able to do the rotation to make the position for landing in a smooth manner, could u guys please help me on this part of the code?

```css
@keyframes rocket{
 0%{
  transform:translate(-10vw);
 }
 40%{
  transform:translate(40vw);

 }
 70%{
  transform:translate(70vw, -15vw) rotate(-90deg);
 }
 100%{
  transform:translate(70vw, 0) rotate(-90deg);
 }
}

.rocketA{
 margin-top: 150px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: pink;
 animation-name: rocket;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: normal;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class='rocketA'></div>
```

If anyone finds this helpful here it goes the solution I found to make it better, thank for all the help.

***SOLUTION***

```css
@keyframes rocket {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-10vw);
  }
  52% {
    transform: translate(45vw);
  }
  52% {
    transform: translate(45vw, -0vw) rotate(-5deg);
  }
  54% {
    transform: translate(48vw, -0.5vw) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: translate(51vw, -1vw) rotate(-15deg);
  }
  58% {
    transform: translate(54vw, -1.5vw) rotate(-20deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(57vw, -2vw) rotate(-25deg);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translate(60vw, -2.5vw) rotate(-30deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: translate(63vw, -3vw) rotate(-35deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(66vw, -3.5vw) rotate(-40deg);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(69vw, -4vw) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(72vw, -4.5vw) rotate(-50deg);
  }
  72% {
    transform: translate(75vw, -5vw) rotate(-55deg);
  }
  74% {
    transform: translate(78vw, -5.5vw) rotate(-60deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(81vw, -6vw) rotate(-65deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: translate(83vw, -6.5vw) rotate(-70deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(85vw, -7vw) rotate(-75deg);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translate(88vw, -7.5vw) rotate(-80deg);
  }
  84% {
    transform: translate(91vw, -8.5vw) rotate(-85deg);
  }
  86%, 96% {
    transform: translate(94vw, -9vw) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  96%, 100% {
    transform: translate(94vw, 0) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  
}

.rocketA {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
  animation-name: rocket;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class='rocketA'></div>
```

Comment: so between the 70% and 100% I need to make the rotation turn until it gets to the -90deg? is that it?

Comment: @AndreFernandes why not just use `linear`? Your `translate` values are progressive it looks smooth see my answer demo

Comment: I understand, I think I'm going to give a couple of tries.

Comment: Very smooth, excellent job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `animation-timing-function: linear;`

### Demo

```css
@keyframes rocket{
 0%{
  transform:translate(-10vw);
 }
 40%{
  transform:translate(40vw);

 }
 70%{
  transform:translate(70vw, -15vw) rotate(-90deg);
 }
 100%{
  transform:translate(70vw, 5vw) rotate(-90deg);
 }
}

.rocketA{
 margin-top: 150px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: pink;
 animation-name: rocket;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: normal;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class='rocketA'></div>
```

Comment: thanks, @zer00ne  that make it smoother, even if it isnt the experience that I look for, I still need it to make the curve smoother, but ty.

Comment: @AndreFernandes What do you mean by "make the curve smoother"? How would it be smoother?

Comment: I was talking about the code I wrote at the solution, check it out. I meant the curve to make the "rocket" (pink div for test) straight for landing.